# Kubernetes: Mongodb with peristent storage

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, persistent-volumes

I'm trying to deploy a MongoDB pod on a minikube instance.
I've mounted a local directory on the minikube machine and I want MongoDB to write data in this directory.

Minikube is started using this command line:

```
minikube start --mount --mount-string=/home/minikube:/data/host
```

My `mongo-deploy.yaml` looks like the following

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: mongodb-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongodb
          image: mongo
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongodb-data
              mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
        - name: mongodb-data
          hostPath:
            path: /data/host/mongo
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - name: mongodb
      protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

The problem is when the pod starts, I got this error

```
{"log":"{\"t\":{\"$date\":\"2021-01-17T23:27:54.524+00:00\"},\"s\":\"E\",  \"c\":\"STORAGE\",  \"id\":20557,   \"ctx\":\"initandlisten\",\"msg\":\"DBException in initAndListen, terminating\",\"attr\":{\"error\":\"IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db\"}}\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-01-17T23:27:54.524391471Z"}
```

I'm pretty sure it's all about folder permission.
I've tried to set a `chmod 777` on the local folder but it doesn't work.

What is the correct way to persist data from minikube in the local machine ?

Comment: could you please change ownership of data folder to mongodb. `# chown -R mongodb.mongodb /data/db` or can check uid of mongodb user and pass below command in yaml file `command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R UID:GID /data/db"]` just above **volumeMounts:** line.

Comment: what is your host OS. What is your minikube driver?

Comment: My host OS is Ubuntu 18.04 and my minikube driver is Virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same symptom. I agree with OP that it is due to ownership.

In the common Mongo image, UID for the MongoDB user is 999. However, inserting a command or init container did not succeed for me.

What *did* succeed was adding a `securityContext` annotation to the pod spec:

```
securityContext:
  fsGroup: 999
```

I found that here:
https://www.edureka.co/community/35763/set-volume-mount-user-group-and-file-permissions-kubernetes

This seems like the way.